# Mongoose find by reference field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a channel schema like this:

```
const channelSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
    }
  }
);
```

And this is the feedback schema:

```
const feedbackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  channelId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "channel",
    require: true
  }
});
```

How can I find the feedback by channel name?

```
Feedback.find({channelId.name : 'something'})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You cant query for a property on an object that doest exists, I would suggest first querying for the channel, grabbing the id and doing the lookup from there.

```
const channel = await Channel.findOne({ name });
const feedback = await Feedback.find({ channelId: channel._id })
```

Comment: This works. Since I am new to mongoDB I wonder if that is a best/recommended solution?

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't have any reference from channel schema to feedback schema, you can use [populate-virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) feature of mongoose.

The required changes are like this:

1-)  replace your channel schema like this to use virtual populate:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const channelSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

// Virtual populate
channelSchema.virtual("feedbacks", {
  ref: "feedback",
  foreignField: "channelId",
  localField: "_id"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("channel", channelSchema);
```

2-) Use the following query to find  feedbacks of a given channel name:

Please note that I hard coded channel name in the query, you can read it from request body or request query or request params.

```
router.get("/feedback", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Channel.findOne({ name: "Channel 1" }).populate({
    path: "feedbacks"
  });

  res.send(result);
});
```

The response will be like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5de5509476a9c34048c1d23d",
    "name": "Channel 1",
    "__v": 0,
    "feedbacks": [
      {
        "_id": "5de5512d7d87de2d4c6b38d2",
        "channelId": "5de5509476a9c34048c1d23d",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5de551357d87de2d4c6b38d3",
        "channelId": "5de5509476a9c34048c1d23d",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "id": "5de5509476a9c34048c1d23d"
  }
]
```

Or if you are only interested to feedbacks, you can access them by `result.feedbacks`:

```
router.get("/feedback", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Channel.findOne({ name: "Channel 1" }).populate({
    path: "feedbacks"
  });

  res.send(result.feedbacks);
});
```

Which will give you an array of feedbacks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5de5512d7d87de2d4c6b38d2",
        "channelId": "5de5509476a9c34048c1d23d",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5de551357d87de2d4c6b38d3",
        "channelId": "5de5509476a9c34048c1d23d",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use plugin [mongoose-find-by-reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-find-by-reference).

## Step.1 install

```
npm i -S mongoose-find-by-reference
```

[npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-find-by-reference)
[Github link](https://github.com/cheezone/mongoose-find-by-reference)

## Step.2 `plugin()` the plugin

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Require mongoose-find-by-reference
const { MongooseFindByReference } = require('mongoose-find-by-reference');

await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test")

const channelSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
    }
  }
);


const feedbackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  channelId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "channel",
    require: true
  }
});

// Execute function plugin() on schema with Reference paths
feedbackSchema.plugin(MongooseFindByReference);


const Channel= mongoose.model('channel', channelSchema );
const Feedback= mongoose.model('feedback', feedbackSchema );
```

## Step.3 just use it!

```
const { _id } = await Channel.create({ name: "C" })

await Feedback.create({channelId : _id})

/** Its conditions will be auto automatically replaced with :
{
  channelId: {
    $in: [
      /* ObjectIDs for Eligible channels */
    ],
  },
}
 */
const findResult = await Feedback.find({channelId.name : 'C'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Query using the `populate` method

```js
try {
  const data = await feedBack.find(...).populate({ path: 'channel', match: { id: 'xxx' }).exec();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```