# How to query for an object within an array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongoose and I'm having trouble querying for specific objects within an array.

My data model looks like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": "61b0d6637e169ddebf72c18a",
      "name": "Brian Test",
      "email": "briantest@gmail.com",
      "password": "xxx",
      "accountType": "type1",
      "__v": 0,
      "title": "title1",
      "about": "about1",
      "education": [
        {
          "recordId": 1,
          "institution": "institution1",
          "title": "title1"
        },
        {
          "recordId": 2,
          "institution": "institution2",
          "title": "title2"
        },
        {
          "recordId": 3,
          "institution": "institution3",
          "title": "title3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The query I need is to perform a crud on education records. For it I'll have the user ID and the education record ID.

I'm not sure how to nest the education record query within the user query.
I've tried something like this but It's not working.

```
let user = await User.findOne({_id: req.user.user.id})
let recordToUpdate = await user.education.findOne({recordId: req.body.recordId})
console.log(recordToUpdate)
```

I'll appreciate if you could give examples for reading, updating and deleting records aswell.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose find by reference field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138481/mongoose-find-by-reference-field)

Comment: I guess I could use a different schema for education records, and reference it to the user by user id, but I wonder how could I query this by keeping it all in the same schema.

Comment: In general, you could use the Array Operators to work with the _array_ type field data; see [Array Query and Projection Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#array) and the [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#array).